# Approximate sampling from unknown distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose I want to sample from a (discrete) distribution $p$. However, one often knows the probability $p(x)$ of sampling $x$ only up to normalizing constant which can be costly to compute. Then one can still sample approximately from $p$ if one can sample from a different distribution $q$ with $q(x) \ge \epsilon p(x)$ for all $x$. This is done [here](http://stat.rutgers.edu/home/rongchen/papers/eigen.pdf) by constructing Metropolis Markov chain. One needs roughly $1/\epsilon$ samples to get close to $p$.

Are there some other ways of achieving the same result without constructing a chain? For example, the first thing that I would try to analyze is something like importance sampling: one first samples sufficiently many samples from $q$, then give each sampled $x$ weight $p(x)/q(x)$ and samples the final result according to the new weights (note that it suffices to know $p$ only up to normalizing constant). What are the guarantees for the above two stage algorithm?

Comment: What are examples of discrete probabilities being known and the normalizing constant being hard to compute?

Comment: I don't understand. What is costly, summing over p(x)??

Comment: Sorry, I did not clarify it enough. [Oftentimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution) you can compute in O(1) the weight w(x) according to which you want to sample, but to turn these weights into probabilities you need to sum over all x in O(n) time to compute normalizing constant.